# Porque meu status "change" aparece como um valor negativo no Stack Overflow em Português?

Tags: suporte, pergunta-específica, stackexchange, stackoverflow

Conforme aparece na reputação **change** no [**StackExchange**](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/273/month/pt-stackoverflow/2015-10-01/26539):

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Se entendi bem, este é o *Rank change* que em português seria algo como *mudança de posição*. Agora imagine que você esta em uma corrida, significa que em relação aos outros usuários você perdeu 5 posições no último mês, não porque você esta pior, mas porque alguém está melhor que você.

Note que o link que você enviou mostra pelo mês, sendo que o -5 posições foi neste mês comparado ao mês passado provavelmente. Note também que na parte de superior existe estes links:

<kbd>[image: Lista dos links]</kbd>

Isto provavelmente quer dizer que comparado ao último mês e a pontuação de todos usuários da comunidade, você teve uma **evolução menor** no mês atual (talvez em questão de porcentagem).

Cada link:

- *Week* é seu rank por semana
- *Month* é seu rank por mês
- *Quarter* é seu rank por trimestre
- *Year* é seu rank por ano
- *All time* é seu rank desde que a comunidade existe (ou você é cadastrado)

Veja o meu caso de exemplo (a duas semanas atrás):

- Avancei 16 posições (+16) na última semana
- Perdi 4 posições (-4) no último mês
- Perdi 8 posições (-8) no último trimestre
- Avancei 90 posições (+90) no último ano

Eu não tive perda de pontos consideráveis no último trimeste, ao contrário eu ganhei uma pontuação considerável, mesmo assim aparece -8 por exemplo, isto quer dizer que alguém (um ou mais usuários) me passou em questão de pontuação durante este período.

Veja hoje (13/11):

- Avancei 16 posições (-5) na última semana
- Perdi 4 posições (+5) no último mês
- Perdi 8 posições (-6) no último trimestre
- Avancei 90 posições (+91) no último ano

Veja agora estou com -5 na última semana, note como os valores mudaram.

Por tanto se quer ver a sua posição de todos os tempos clique em [All time](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/273/alltime/pt-stackoverflow).

> Me corrijam se tiver algum erro de interpretação do *leagues* :)

Comment: E quando você pensa que já viu tudo... é impressionante, surreal a minúcia das stats do SO.

Comment: É o pessoal da SE (agora SO) leva o gamification como o principal recurso de sucesso dos sites :)